# How to convert the special character when reading into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a .csv file including the following data:

```
Publication,First Name,Last Name,Constituency,Caucus,Province,Date,Time,Page,Text
Hansard - 59,FayÃ§al,El-Khoury PauzÃ©,Laval-Les ÃŽles,Lib.,QC,2022-04-27,14:23:08,,"Mr. FayÃ§al El-Khoury"
```

I want to be able to read correctlty the word with special character like `FayÃ§al` to be `Fayçal`.
I tried :

```
import pandas as pd 

file_name = "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Results.csv"
df =pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', encoding_errors='ignore')
df
```

But unfortunatly, still getting the strange character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the dataframe with encoding set to 'latin_1'

```
df =pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='latin_1', encoding_errors='ignore')
```

**UPDATE:**

Otherwise, if this does not solve the problem you could try apply encoding column by column.

Try this function should do the trick

```
def encode_serie(serie):
    return serie.str.encode('latin_1', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

df = df.astype(str)
df = df.apply(lambda x:encode_serie(x))
```

If also this does not work, try `to_csv` with encoding set to 'utf-8' and try to read again the csv and rerun the function above.

Comment: with 'latin' is still give the same result. With the second option I get : AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: yes, you right, let me fix it.

Comment: @bib Updated, let me know if it works

Comment: lerardi thanks it is working now. But if I have a big file applying the ecode_serie method will be ineffecient.

Comment: Yes, it is time consuming since it will scan every cell in every column. Maybe you could try to save your csv with parameter utf-8 `pd.save_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')` and reload it again. Maybe it will be more fast and practical

Comment: Leardi, this command is not correct ;(